# Why did UIAlertView dismissAnimated: work at all?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uialertview

I was just trying to dismiss a UIAlertView using the following call:

```
[serverConnectionClosedAlertView dismissAnimated:YES];
```

I did some testing and everything worked nicely. When I got back to the Xcode window I saw the warning, "UIAlertView may not respond to '-dismissAnimated'. I looked up the documentation and noticed that this method is indeed not defined on UIAlertView or even UIView. The correct call should have been

```
[serverConnectionClosedAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

So, I am wondering

1. Why did Xcode suggest the original method name (I had pressed ESC to get the list of suggestions and just picked the method above; old Eclipse/Java habit, I guess), and
2. Why did the code work at all? It actually did dismiss the UIAlertView without any crashes or log entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact called `dismissAnimated:` in previous versions of the SDK. It has since either been deprecated or made a private API in favor of `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`, but it'll still work if you call it.

Comment: Ah. Cool, that makes sense... I thought there might be a miracle involved somewhere along the line. Thank you.